# Узнать есть ли комментарии в посте/страницы wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Нужно узнать есть ли комментарии т.е не включены они или нет, а именно существует хотя бы один комментарий, и вывести перед (Loop) строку

**Комментарии пользователей : 2**

Комментарии в single.php выводяться так

```
<?php comments_template('', true ); ?>
```

Как мне сделать это ? смотрел в function.php да там есть построение loop комментариев, но там нельзя никуда вставить текст, что бы он не повторялся в loop. Так как же тогда сделать ? нужно как то из вне ? или... просто только начиная осваивать систему wordpress и не понимаю некоторые вещи.

Answer (score 2):

Количество комментариев для поста с номером $post_id можно получить так:

```
$number = get_comments_number( $post_id );
```